# VSCode unable to connect SSH to raspberry pi 4

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, raspberry-pi4

I'm facing an annoying problem which just popped out of the blue overnight: VScode will not, under any circumstances connect to my raspberry pi 4 via ssh. I'm using VScode insiders with the remote-ssh extension and it worked like a charm the weeks before.

**What works:**

- Putty connects seamlessly over LAN or WiFi.
- ssh is enabled on rpi4
- i am using the correct IP which i get from hostname -I in the terminal

**What doesn't work:**

- neither "raspberrypi" nor "*my correct IP*" work. Right after selecting "Linux" in the selection process it throws the error "Could not establish connection to "*my correct IP*""
- uninstalling VScode insiders and deleting all related files in docs and appdata changes nothing after reinstallation

**What i observed:**

This happened to me before in VScode for no reason and was unfixable. On a forum post someone recommended using insiders, which fixed the problem but now VScode insiders seems to be affected by this as well. Whenever a connection couldn't be established, two problems pop up in my extensions tab:

"Error while loading extensions. Error"

"We cannot conect to the Marketplace at this time, please try again later."

Especially the last one gives me a feeling that this is a bug within VScode. I'll gladly take the blame if it's on my behalf, i just want to fix the problem.

Similar things have been mentioned here:

["Extension host terminated unexpectedly" in vs code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61160837/extension-host-terminated-unexpectedly-in-vs-code/61161079#61161079)

[Remote SSH in Visual Studio Code does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61138664/remote-ssh-in-visual-studio-code-does-not-work)

but are unsolved or don't quite fit my description. Thank you for your time and help.

Screenshot of my VScode insiders: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ihUu.jpg